# Standard name / symbol for intersection in Brouwerian lattices

Tags: reference-request, terminology, lattice-theory

A Brouwerian lattice has a lower adjoint $\cdot - B$ to $B\lor\cdot$. It is called *pseudodifference*. The main reference is http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969038

Once you have pseudodifference, you can define the symmetric pseudodifference

$$ A\mathbin\Delta B = ( A- B)\lor (B-A)$$

and it is known that

$$ A\lor B - A \land B = A\mathbin\Delta B$$

Now, we can also compute

$$ A\lor B - A\mathbin\Delta B$$

Is there a name for this binary operator? This is in general not $A\land B$.